# No Wi-Fi Adapter Found Ubuntu 18.04.2 Dell 3530

Tags: iwlwifi

"No Wi-Fi Adapter Found" message shows in WiFi Settings. I can't connect or view any WiFi network.

```
$ uname -r
4.18.0-25-generic

$ nmcli device status
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION         
eno2    ethernet  connected  Wired connection 1
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --     

$ lspci | grep Wireless
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] (rev 10)

$ dmesg | grep iwl
[   80.306544] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   80.325892] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 38.c0e03d94.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   80.374182] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9560, REV=0x318
[   81.408054] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x3, CPU2 Status: 0x240f
[   81.408057] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[   81.420104] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[ 1326.205714] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 38.c0e03d94.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[ 1326.218447] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9560, REV=0x318
[ 1327.247770] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x3, CPU2 Status: 0x240f
[ 1327.247780] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[ 1327.260590] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

It's a fresh installation. I also did apt-update and apt-upgrade.

```
$ rfkill list all
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

modprobe iwlwifi returns no output.

### **found fix:**

Go to BIOS and disable two options: "Control WLAN radio" and "Control WWAN radio" under category "Power Management" -> "Wireless Radio Control".

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution the made Ubuntu wind the wireless adapter?

Comment: I returned laptop to service and they told me they changed some BIOS options which fixed the issue. Don't know which options though.

Comment: Today, few days after firmware update I experienced the issue again. Ubuntu showed "wifi hardware disabled" message in wifi selector. I fixed it by entering the BIOS and disabling two options: "Control WLAN radio" and "Control WWAN radio" under category "Power Management" -> "Wireless Radio Control". Now wifi never gets disabled.

Comment: Since above posts this issue occurred a few more times. Turning those 2 options on and off again in BIOS and then saving the BIOS solves the issue. It seems like a bug in dell's BIOS.